# Spring boot version 2.5.5 unable to create docker image for copy command

Tags: spring-boot, docker, build.gradle

After upgrading my spring-boot application from spring-boot version 2.3.9 to 2.5.12
We have started getting below exception. Not sure if there is change related to docker in spring boot version 2.5.12

With previous version it was working fine but after changing gradle to 6.8 and spring-boot version this issue started ... any workaround to fix this issue?
This is the command that causes error in Dockerfile

```
ENV APP_HOME=/app/z-api/

COPY --from=build "${APP_HOME}build/libs/z-api-*.jar" app.jar
```

> COPY --from=build "${APP_HOME}build/libs/z-api-*.jar" app.jar
> When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are now two jars in `build/libs` that match `z-api-*.jar`. This is due to Spring Boot 2.5 no longer disabling the `jar` task by default. From the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#gradle-default-jar-and-war-tasks):

> The Spring Boot Gradle Plugin no longer automatically disables the standard Gradle jar and war tasks. Instead we now apply a classifier to those tasks.
>
> If you prefer to disable those tasks, the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable-and-plain) includes updated examples.

You could update your `COPY` command so that it doesn’t match the `-plain.jar` that’s now produced by the `jar` task. Alternatively, you could disable the `jar` task:

```
jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @andy-wilkinson explained, the reason is that 2 jar files are generated by Gradle as

```
<appname>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
<appname>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
```

If you prefer that the plain archive isn’t built at all, disable its task.

If you are using Kotlin with Gradle, add the following script to `build.gradle.kts`

```
tasks.named<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = false
}
```

Read more on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives